# Laravel : Form Data Binding

Tags: php, forms, data-binding, laravel-5

I need to bind the data to the related field using Form data binding , but the data does not showed on the fields at all.I don't know what the problem exactly that prevent the data to appear.

**Controller:**

```
public function edit($id){
$datum = RatingDatum::findorfail(1);
 return view('rating.index',compact('datum'));
}
```

View:

```
<div class="plan bg-plan">
   {!! Form::model($datums,['method' => 'PATCH','action'=>'RatingDataController@update'],$datums->id]) !!}  
   <div class="radio">
           <label>
             {!! Form::radio('customize_question_id')!!}{{$datums->value}}
            </label>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::label('comment','Comment :') !!}
       {!! Form::textarea('comment' ,null,['class'=>'form-control', 'rows' => 4]) !!}

       {!! Form::label('reference','Reference:') !!}
       {!! Form::textarea('reference',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'rows' => 1]) !!}
   </div>
       {!! Form::submit('Submit Data', ['class' => 'btn btn-success submit']) !!}
       {!! Form::close() !!}
   </div>
```

dd($datum);

```
#attributes: array:15 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "organisation_id" => 8
    "sector_id" => 1
    "country_id" => 1
    "dimension_id" => 12
    "question_angle_id" => 1
    "customize_criteria_id" => 33
    "customize_question_id" => 7591
    "question_weight" => 20
    "actual_score" => 75
    "value" => "The company has made a formal commitment to promoting voluntary community initiatives and has set up quantitative targets in this regard."
    "comment" => ""
    "reference" => ""
    "created_at" => "2015-12-21 11:28:38"
    "updated_at" => "2015-12-21 12:22:25"
  ]
```

Comment: As you could see that `reference`  and `comment` are empty so the text boxes will be empty

Comment: it is data binding , the data will be add automatically to the related fields even if the field is null

Comment: I mean to say that the values from the database are empty. Check your `dd` data

Comment: The problem also on the radio button :(

Comment: `{!! Form::radio('customize_question_id', $datums->customize_question_id, $datums->customize_question_id != null ? 'true' : 'false')!!}`

Comment: Thank you so much it is worked :)

Answer (score 0):

The data is not showing up in the form is because you are referencing the wrong variable.

You are passing `$datum` and in the view form, you are accessing `$datums`. That is the reason why your form is empty.

**Solution:**

Do either of the following:

- Update controller method's `$datum` to `$datums`

*OR*

- Update form model `$datums` to `$datum`